# Allocate constant strings in container contiguously

Tags: c++, string, optimization, memory-management

Lets say I have a `std::vector` of `const std::string`s.

```
std::vector<const std::string> strs;
```

Now the default behavior here is that the actual string containers can be allocated anywhere on the heap, which pretty much disables any prefetching of data when iterating over the contained strings.

```
strs.push_back("Foo"); // allocates char block on heap
strs.push_back("Boo"); // allocates char block on heap
```

However, since the strings are "const" I would like the char blocks to be allocated contiguously or close to each other (when possible) in order to have the most efficient cache behavior when iterating over the strings.

Is there any way to achieve this behavior?

Comment: In addition to the problems shown in the answers, you cannot even have a vector of const objects. The requirements for the stored type include being copyable (or movable, depending on C++ version). Const objects would fail that.

Comment: @BoPersson: Good point. I guess it's up to the programmer to make sure that the strings are not changed.

Comment: If you make the vector itself const, its members cannot be changed. However, neither the vector nor the strings will really be aware of that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a custom allocator known as a memory region allocator. You can look on Wikipedia or Google for more information, but the basic idea is something akin to the hardware stack- allocate one large chunk and then simply increment the pointer to mark it as used. It can serve many contiguous requests very quickly but can't deal with frees and allocations- all freeing is done at once.

Comment: Well, it can deal with freeing in a limited way - when you free the most recently allocated block, you can just reset the internal pointer.

Comment: @DeadMG can you also address the issue with small string optimisation which I've mentioned in my answer?

Answer (score 1):

If it really is that simple - pushing strings that will never change, it is easy to write your own allocator. Allocate a large block of memory, set a pointer `free` to offset 0 in the block. When you need storage for a new string `strncpy` it to `free` and increase `free` with the `strlen`. Keep track of the end of the memory block and allocate another block when needed.

Comment: Mocking around with C-style string handling is not a good idea. `std::basic_string` is allocator-aware, so I'd use that.

Answer (score 1):

Not really.

`std::string` isn't a POD, it doesn't keep its contents "inside of the object". What's more - it doesn't even require to store its contents in a single memory block.

Also a `std::vector` (as all arrays) needs its contents to be of one type (= of equal size), so you can't make a literal "array" of strings of different lengths.

Your best shot is to assume a length and use `std::vector<std::array<char, N> >`

If you need really different lengths, an alternative is just a `std::vector<char>` for the data plus a `std::vector<unsigned>` for the indices where consecutive strings start.

---

Rolling your own allocator for the string is a tempting idea, you could base it on `std::vector<char>` and then roll up your own `std::basic_string` on it, then make a collection of those.

Note that you are actually depending much on a specific `std::string` implementation. Some do have an internal buffer of N chars and only allocate memory externally if the string length is bigger than the buffer. If that's the case on your implementation, you still wouldn't get a contiguous memory for the whole buffer of strings.

On that grounds, I conclude that with `std::string` you won't be generally able to accomplish what you want (unless you rely on a specific STL implementation) and you need to provide another string implementation to suit your needs.

Comment: Well, what I had in mind was some sort of custom allocator to use for the strings, e.g. std::vector<std::basic_string<char, std::char_traits<char>, contigious_string_allocator<char>>. Unsure how that would work though.

Comment: Hmm I figured that out after reading the thread/answers again; see the edit

Comment: `std::string` is indirectly forced to store it's contents in contiguous memory. For certain in C++11, I think also already in c++03. Every major implementation (MSVC,GCC,libc++) uses contiguous `std::string`s.

Comment: @up but still there's the possibility of using either internal or external buffer, right?

Comment: @Kos: That's called the "small string optimization". Since the buffer is internal, it will be allocated at the same time the vector space is allocated, which means it is even more compact than the external buffer version.

Comment: But note that if the optimization kicks in for strings of length <N, then some strings in the collection would be optimised and some wouldn't, which contradicts the OP's requirement for the whole string buffer to be contiguous.

Comment: @Kos: on MSVC for example, the small buffer is 16 chars long. Either you make sure every string is below that size, or you zero-pad the string using the `(char const*, size_t)` constructor and intialize it with your string and the rest being 0s.

Answer (score 1):

A custom allocator is great, but why not store all the strings in a single `std::vector<char>` or `std::string`, and access the original strings by offset?

Simple and effective.

Comment: Because then when I want to access a specific string I would need to copy the sub-string into a new std::string which I return.

Comment: Since the strings can't change size, this is indeed a good option.

Comment: @ronag: You might be able to simulate a string reference with `pair<iterator,iterator>` into the `std::string` or `std::vector<char>`.

Comment: @Xeo: Good idea. Although it is not as elegant, it would be a simpler solution than a custom allocator.

Comment: @ronag: Immutable strings (also called ref-strings) are really something C++ is missing. It would help tremendously with things like string literals, which don't need to be copied so-long you don't write to them.

Comment: @Xeo: LLVM has a `StringRef` class which should fit the bill nicely: http://llvm.org/docs/doxygen/html/classllvm_1_1StringRef.html

Comment: @rubenvb: Yes, that's a nice thing to have, but it interfaces badly with `std::string`. The problem is, that `std::string` is not aware that it is built from a string literal for example, and thus only needs to copy-on-write. CoW, however, is another problem in itself and I really have no idea how to efficiently solve it for `std::string`. :(

Answer (score 0):

You can always write a private allocator (second template parameter for `std::vector`) that will allocate all the strings from a continuous pool. **Also** you can use `std::basic_string` instead of `std::string` (which is a private case of `std::basic_string`), which allows specifying your own allocator similarly. Generally I would say its a case of "premature optimization", but I trust you've measured and saw a performance hit here... I believe the price to pay would be some memory wasted, though.

Comment: I don't think it's enough to have a private allocator for std::vector, one would also need one for std::string.

Comment: Here's an example of using a scoped allocator for strings in a vector: http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/C++0xFAQ.html#scoped-allocator

Answer (score -1):

A vector is guaranteed to be contiguous memory and is
interoperable with an array. It is not a singly linked list.

"Contiguity is in fact part of the vector abstraction. It’s so important, in fact,   the C++03 standard was amended to explicitly add the guarantee."

Source : http://herbsutter.com/2008/04/07/cringe-not-vectors-are-guaranteed-to-be-contiguous/

Use `reserve()` to force it to be contiguous and not reallocate.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    // create empty vector for strings
    vector<const string> sentence;

    // reserve memory for five elements to avoid reallocation
    sentence.reserve(5);

    // append some elements
    sentence.push_back("Hello,");
    sentence.push_back("how");
    sentence.push_back("are");
    sentence.push_back("you");
    sentence.push_back("?");

    // print elements separated with spaces
    copy (sentence.begin(), sentence.end(),
          ostream_iterator<string>(cout," "));
    cout << endl;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: The vector might be contiguous, but the memory blocks allocated by different std::string:s to store the string data are not.